# Are questions about sources of jokes on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The question [Is this Heisenberg joke actually real?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8494/65) is closed for the following reason:

> This question does not appear to be about history of science and math, within the scope defined in the help center.

The [help center](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists these topics:

> - What influenced a certain scientist or mathematician's work in a certain topic?
> - Who discovered or invented this formula or theory?

It is unclear whether question about source for jokes on-topic or not.

FWIW, I have asked a similar question, and it's welcomed: [In a popular anecdote, who took 20 minutes to decide that a thing was obvious?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7247/65)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is easy to draw up any unambiguous criteria for this. For me personally, the older question seemed more relevant to the site, since it concerns mathematicians *in their capacity as mathematicians*, as opposed to the question about the Heisenberg story/joke. I realize, however, that this might be different for other people and think that it is a good idea in principle to handle such questions on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Do you mean that even if Heisenberg really said that, it's still irrelevant to his work in specific, and to the history of science in general?

Comment: Not only is it irrelevant to his work and the history of science, but it is in fact almost independent of the fact that he was a physicist. In the other question, the story at least involves the mathematician doing his job as a mathematician. But let me stress again that this is a matter of taste.